# Remote Debug iOS 6/7 WebViews/Mobile Safari using the Ubuntu Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, webview, safari, web-inspector

Is there any way to inspect and remote debug iOS 6/7 App WebViews/ Mobile Safari using  **Ubuntu Chrome**?

Just like [Remote Debugging Chrome on Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) or with any tools like [ADB Plugin for remote debugging Chrome on Android (Now deprecated)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb/dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage)